# What happens to characters not specified in the first part of Perl's tr/// operator?

Tags: perl, tr

I am using Perl for string manipulation and that involves use of the reverse function and of tr to translate my string.
The script reads some strings and then performs following:

```
$revread = reverse($newword);
$revread =~ tr/TACGN/ATGCN/;
```

So the word is reversed and then gets translated--reverse complement.
I have following question:

What if

```
$revread=~ tr/TACG/ATGC/;
```

is used. In this case if "N" is found will it be skipped? as in tr I have nothing there to translate it to OR it will be printed as just as "N".

Comment: How about testing it in a simple 2-line perl program?

Comment: Or reading `perldoc perlop`? Grep for `tr/`?

Comment: Why would you think that "N" would be removed? Makes no sense to me.

Comment: Perhaps the OP is concerned with any unexpected behavior and that's why he's asking

Comment: Yes, wanted to make sure that I do not see something unexpected

Answer (score 5):

Yes, anything that is not specified inside to `tr` will be left alone.

The documentation for `tr///` is a little hard to get to as it's detailed examples are listed in [`perldoc perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators)  rather than the usual [`perldoc perlfunc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions.html)

Comment: Thanks. Very clear now. The perl doc cleared other doubts as well...now it will be the first go to place..

Comment: The documentation for tr/// is in perlop, not perlfunc because it's an operator, not a function :-)

Comment: The latest patches to perldoc will now find tr with the -f switch :)

Answer (score 2):

Aleks G has the correct answer: Just try it.

I tried it. I found that:

```
> perl -wE '$x = qq(abcdefg); $x=~ tr/abc/123/; say $x;'
123defg
```

Any characters not found in the transliteration are left as they are. Documentation [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#tr/SEARCHLIST/REPLACEMENTLIST/cdsr).